# linux cat echo two files as one

Tags: json, linux, string, cat

I would like to do this for two .json files from the command line:

```
#echo '[' . (cat file1.json) . ',' . (cat file2.json) . ']'
```

But that is obviously pseudo code.  How would I do this?

Comment: Use the `jq(1)` tool when reading/writing json. It only has minimal support for I/O, but it should be enough for this.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure you mean `'['` for an array, since you don't have keys.

Comment: OP, do you care if your result is valid JSON?

Comment: @WillBarnwell, I edited so that opening and closing braces were [ and ] - and that would be valid json as long as the files are valid json - for example: `[{"address":"123 main"},{"address":"805 Zach"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "[ $(cat file1.json) , $(cat file2.json) ]"
```

Works as long as the files themselves are valid json

Comment: This will never produce valid JSON

Comment: The OP just wanted the working concept illustrated, I'm assuming. The question, as it's written currently, doesn't ask for JSON parsing.

Comment: I know it's unclear, I didn't downvote, just mentioned in case OP or somebody else does care about valid JSON output here

Comment: This is the simplest answer and worked for me.  I edited my question to replace the bookending `{}` with `[]`

Comment: My comment is now invalid as the answer has been edited

Comment: Also this now duplicates part of my answer :P

Answer (score 1):

It is not totally clear what you want the final structure to be, but let me try to help.

I am assuming you have 2 files containing only valid json and guessing from your question that you want to print both files as members of an array.

I'll assume for the sake of examples that `file1.json` looks like this:

```
{"name":"object1"}
```

And `file2.json` like this:

```
{"name":"object2"}
```

This can be done with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), an extremely useful tool for parsing JSON streams, using the `-s/--slurp` option, which reads the whole input stream into one buffer instead of processing each object separately. It has the added bonus of combining the objects into an array. We can use the default 'passthrough' filter `'.'` and pipe both files into an array.

```
cat file1.json file2.json | jq --slurp '.'
```

Will output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "object1"
  },
  {
    "name": "object2"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fksoBbVJP7)

If you want that array inside an object, you can use the filter `{"array":.}`

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PRNmBW6izA)

I highly recommend `jq` for any JSON interaction you plan on doing from a shell, but if you cannot, and must use builtins, you could hack together something like this:

```
echo '['"$(cat file1.json)"','"$(cat file2.json)"']'
```

This solution uses subshells `$()` to execute the commands within them and include their output in the echo.

I again reiterate, use `jq`. It is cleaner, more sturdy, and ensures that input and output are valid JSON.

Comment: Will, upvoted your answer for it's information and usefulness, but the accepted answer was the simplest after I edited my question to use square braces.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
{ cat file1.json ; echo ','; cat file2.json; }
```

Comment: Please include explanation, code only answers are of very little use. Additionally, I don't think this achieves what OP desired, this prints one file, a ',' on a newline and then another file, all in a subshell.